# Configurar android sdk para unity

Tags: android, unity3d, unity, sdk

Amigos estoy en un proyecto en el cual cuenta con realidad aumentada echo en unity, anterior mente se tenia instalado versiones de unity como la 2018 y ahora se tiene la 2019, en el unity hub al ingresar en la parte de install no se puede agregar adiciones a las versiones ya instaladas de unity, pero al contar con android studio instalado en el equipo, por obvias razones se cuenta con el sdk manager instalado, pues al tratar de seleccionar esta carpeta donde se tiene el sdk instaldo unity no me la reconoce y otros programas que utilizan el sdk si me la reconocen como lo es genymotion

Me arroja el siguiente mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría solucionar esto sin tener que volver a descargar e instalar el unity nuevamente

Comment: Has probado a seleccionar el check?

Comment: Con el Unity Hub puedes agregar las extensiones de Android y IOS con la version de Unity que estés usando aunque el proyecto ya esté finalizado.

Answer (score 0):

Hola si quieres convertir tu juego a apk en el unity hub en tu vercion agrega Android, luego te metes a tu proyecto (con la vercion que le as agregado android)
y le das click a build setigs, hay cambias de la que tengas a android, si ta vas a player settings y elijes android va a haber una manera de firmar el archibo,
una ves te hayas cambiado a android apreta build, se ta va a generar un archibo apk ese archibo es tu juego :D.

Comment: Esto luce más como un comentario que una respuesta, en cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en todas partes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), [Es mejor dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/586/por-qu%c3%a9-necesito-50-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n-para-comentar-qu%c3%a9-alternativa-tengo)